# Method not found on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I need to use show the confirm message. 
I am calling the method from 'btnCalculate' clientclick event. It calls the method if it's the first time. but if i click the button the second time, the method is not found. below is my code. Please advice. Thank you so much.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" OnClick="btnYes_Clicked" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Claim" OnClientClick="return(cfrm());"/>

function cfrm() {
        var  consultFee = '0';
        consultFee = $('[id$=txtConsultFee]').val();

        if (consultFee > 500) {
            if (confirm('Confirm?')) {
                $('[id$=btnYes]').click();
            }
        } else {
            $('[id$=btnYes]').click();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the `totalgst` value from? It seems like you are doing `var totalgst = parseFloat(totalgst)` ??? Is the `totalgst` a global value??

Comment: my problem is that if the "btnCalculate" is clicked for the second time, "cfrm()" method is not found... i'm certain that if the method is found, all the calculation and logic are correct...

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering how you are getting your click right at first time because, you haven't declared your `var totalgst` you are directly initializing it!!

You might have to initialize it first:

```
function cfrm(){
var totalgst=584;
totalgst = parseFloat(totalgst).toFixed(4);
............ other code....
}
```

No need to write `OnClientClick="return(cfrm());` you can write `OnClientClick="return cfrm();"` directly.

If i am doing simple alert with your code it seems to be working everytime, you rather check your js function

Comment: thank you for the prompt response.. i tried. but having the same problem.

Comment: @user1527923 i updated the answer
If you are having issues with js code you might have to post your html. :)

Comment: actually, i deleted some of the calculation as the method is too long... i believe if the jquery method is found, it'll b working fine. my main concern is why the method cannot be found if the button is clicked for the second time :(

Comment: Where are you getting this `error`?? in console?? or is it prompting you?

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
OnClientClick="return cfrm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the aspx code like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Claim" OnClientClick="return Confirm();" OnClick="btnYes_Clicked" />
```

And the js code like this:

```
function Confirm() {
    var consultFee = '0';
    consultFee = $('[id$=txtConsultFee]').val();

    if (parseInt(consultFee) > 500) {
        return confirm('Confirm?');
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```